# Whats a keyboard shortcut for cycling through open windows in Mail.app on Yosemite?

Tags: mail.app, shortcut

I'd like to be able to cycle through open message windows in Mail.app using a keyboard shortcut. Is this possible without installing a third-party helper application

Comment: Do You mean `⌘` + `\`` (~)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To cycle through windows of an active application You can use keyboard shortcut: <kbd>⌘ CMD</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> - (<kbd>`</kbd> is the key with `~` tilde).